# Calculate the algebraic expressions in C#

Tags: c#, algebra

Calculate the algebraic expression Z, for which n is inputted by user. Use 2 for loops to solve the problem.

[image]

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float sum = 0;

            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                float p = 1;
                for (int k = 1; k <= i + 2; k++)
                {
                    p *= (3 * k + 2);
                }

                sum += p;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the wrong results, and sometimes the same, in case 3 and 4 return 6200 (which is wrong + the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<=` instead of `<` in the first for loop, and write `i++` instead of `i+=2`.

Also, you don't need to use `float`, as the result will always be an integer. Use `long` instead.

Comment: I did that and I am no longer getting the same results, however, I think the results are wrong still? For input 2, I get answer: 6600. I think the answer is 30 (if I did the math correctly?).

Comment: No. It got the correct solution. You were wrong. :) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28product%283k%2B2%2C+1..i%2B2%29%2C+1..2%29

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this line is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
```

It should be

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

Comment: I did that already, see the update and the results are pretty much the same again...